# Android Studio: Creating new Activity: "package not recognized"

Tags: android-studio

[Package On the Left Dropdown Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2UUo.png)

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You tried to create new Activity by clicking on `layout` folder, not `com.your.package`. You can select proper package by clicking on drop down

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple..
just right click on your package and create new activity.

OR

Just For Your Information if u want to create new layout file then right click on layout folder.....

Just try it

Answer (score 0):

[image: immage]

You shuold change "layout" with the name of you package.

You can read the name of your package in the first line code in your MainActivity.java